# Java String Index Out of Range in Proxy

Tags: java, string, out

Hey Guys my following code is a proxy written in java.
Everytime I try to run it, it throws an String Index out of range:-1 exception, which I don't know how to handle.
I also nee to redirect the request to a specific webpage, if a "bad" word has been written in the URL or the content of the web page.
How do I do that?
Please Help me!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProxyServer{
    //Create the Port the user wants the proxy to be on

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final int portNumber = sc.nextInt();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer();

        proxyServer.start();

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting the SimpleProxyServer ...");
        try {
            //bad list of words
            String bad[]= new String[4];
            bad[0]= "SpongeBob";
             bad[1]= "Britney Spears";
             bad[2]= "Norrköping";
             bad[3]= "Paris Hilton";


            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ProxyServer.portNumber);// this is the socket of the proxy
            System.out.println(serverSocket);
            byte[] buffer= new byte [10000] ;
//
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();    // the client willl be the socket the proxy "accepts"
                boolean badContent =false;      //flag, if the input contains one of the bad words
                InputStream inputstream = clientSocket.getInputStream();    // retreiving request from the client


                int n = inputstream.read(buffer);       //reading buffer and storing its size

                String browserRequest= new String(buffer,0,n+1);  //new String(buffer,0,n);

                String realbrowserRequest =( browserRequest+"Connection close()");

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

                for (int j=0; j<bad.length;j++){                        //checking of the URL contains the bad words
                    if(realbrowserRequest.contains(bad[j])){
                        badContent =true;                               // if yes the flag will be set to true
                    }
                }    

                //if(badContent == true){
                    //System.out.println("bad detected");

//                  try
//                  {
//                    URL url = new URL( "http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDTS04/labs/2011/ass2/error2.html" );
//
//                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
//                      new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() ) );
//
//                    String s;
//
//                    while ( ( s = in.readLine() ) != null )
//                      System.out.println( s );
//
//                    in.close();
//                  }
//                  catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
//                      System.out.println( "MalformedURLException: " + e );
//                  }
//                  catch ( IOException e ) {
//                      System.out.println( "IOException: " + e );
//                  }





               // else{





                System.out.println("Das ist der Browserrequest: \n"+realbrowserRequest);
                System.out.println("Das ist der Erste Abschnitt");


                int start = browserRequest.indexOf(("Host: ") + 6);
                int end = browserRequest.indexOf('\n', start);
                String host = browserRequest.substring(start, end-1  );             //retreiving host

                if(badContent =true)                                                //if the URL already contains inappropriate material
                {
                    URL url = new URL( "http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDTS04/labs/2011/ass2/error2.html" );
                    host = url.getHost();                                           // set the host to the given one
                }
                System.out.println("Connecting to host " + host);

                Socket hostSocket = new Socket(host, 80); //I can change the host over here
                OutputStream HostOutputStream = hostSocket.getOutputStream();
//                PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter (HostOutputStream);
//                writer.println();


                System.out.println("Forwarding request to server");
                HostOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);// but then the buffer that is fetched from the client remains same
                HostOutputStream.flush();


                InputStream HostInputstream = hostSocket.getInputStream();


                    OutputStream ClientGetOutput = clientSocket.getOutputStream();



                System.out.println("Forwarding request from server");

                do {
                    n = HostInputstream.read(buffer);

                    String vomHost = new String(buffer,0,n);
                    System.out.println("\nVom Host\n\n"+vomHost);

                    for(int i=0;i<bad.length;i++){
                        if(vomHost.contains(bad[i])){
                            badContent=true;    
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Receiving " + n + " bytes");
                    if (n > 0) {                        // && badContent == false

                        ClientGetOutput.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                } while (n>0  && badContent == false);                          //n>0&& badContent == false
                if (badContent == true){


                }
                ClientGetOutput.flush();
                hostSocket.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("End of communication");
                }


            }


         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            }   
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception ? Post the stack trace

Comment: There are several issues with your code. For example, your content is alwys bad: `if(badContent =true)` . Please try to be more precise with the error discription.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here :

```
int start = browserRequest.indexOf(("Host: ") + 6);
```

This means you are doing this :

```
int start = browserRequest.indexOf("Host: 6");
```

`6` is being concatenated to `"Host : "`

Try this :

```
int start = browserRequest.indexOf("Host: ") + 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code:

1) Change the line :

```
int start = browserRequest.indexOf(("Host: ") + 6);
```

To:

```
int start = browserRequest.indexOf("Host:") + 6;
```

As mentioned in `ToYonos`'s answer, becuase it is wrong.

2) You have to make sure that the two variables `start` and `end` are not equal to -1(if they doesn't exist in `browserRequest`):

```
if(end>start && start>0)
{
  String host = browserRequest.substring(start, end-1  ); 
}
```

This will avoid many Exceptions.

Comment: Thank you I Kind of changed most of my code and it works now. (If I add the last if statement in all cases ;) )

Comment: Well now I have the question of the filtering, I want a GET request to the NEW URL if the requested URL OR The webpage content contains one of the "bad" words.
How do I do that?